# Type [NSNumber] has no subscript members

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a generic class for Gradient class but i am getting this error.
Any help will be appreciated with explanation.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var FirstColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var SecondColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass{
        get{
            return CAGradientLayer.self
        }
    }
    func updateView(){
        var layer  = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer

            layer.colors[FirstColor.cgColor, SecondColor.cgColor]
            layer.locations[NSNumber[0.5]]  
    } 
}
```

I am getting the error in these two lines-

```
layer.colors[FirstColor.cgColor, SecondColor.cgColor]
layer.locations[NSNumber[0.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the equal sign:

```
layer.colors = [FirstColor.cgColor, SecondColor.cgColor]
layer.locations = [NSNumber(value: 0.5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber has an initialiser that accepts a Double, however you're using square brackets by mistake which represent an attempt to access a subscript member.

Change `layer.locations[NSNumber[0.5]]` to `layer.locations[NSNumber(value:  0.5)]`